# accept multiple domain in zone file

Tags: bind

I have zone file like this for domain `maindomain.com`

```
$TTL 14400
maindomain.com. IN SOA ns1.maindomain.com. webmaster@maindomain.com. (
  2013120716 ; serial
  14400 ; refresh
  3600 ; retry
  1209600 ; expire
  7200 ; negative cache
) ;

; name servers
@  IN  NS  ns1.maindomain.com.
@  IN  NS  ns2.maindomain.com.

; mail
; maindomain.com.  IN  MX  10  mail.maindomain.com.

; name servers
maindomain.com.  IN  A  4.2.2.1
ns1  IN  A  4.2.2.1
ns2  IN  A  4.2.2.2

; cname
www  IN  CNAME  maindomain.com.
```

But i need to bind another domains like `anotherdomain.com`, `exampledomain.net` to this server. I set dns for these domains to `ns1.maindomain.com` and `ns2.maindomain.com`.
So I must create zone file for another domains. for example :

```
$TTL 14400
anotherdomain.com. IN SOA ns1.maindomain.com. webmaster@maindomain.com. (
  2013120716 ; serial
  14400 ; refresh
  3600 ; retry
  1209600 ; expire
  7200 ; negative cache
) ;

; cname
www  IN  CNAME  anotherdomain.com.
```

I dont need name server for `anotherdoamin.com` ...

```
zone "maindomain.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/master/maindomain.com.db";
};

zone "anotherdomain.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/master/anotherdomain.com.db";
};
```

Also i have an error in zone file:

```
named-checkzone anotherdomain.com /etc/bind/zones/master/anotherdomain.com.db
zone anotherdomain.com/IN: has no NS records
zone anotherdomain.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Comment: There must be NS records in each zone.  They don't have to be **in the domain in question**, but every zone must have them.

Answer (score 0):

One domain per zone file. Just edit your named.conf file to use a different file for each zone.

```
zone "anotherdomain.com"    {  type master;  file "anotherdomain.DB";  };
```

Comment: Update question. I already added to `named.conf.local`